# How can I model a scalable set of definition/term pairs?

Tags: dictionary, scalability, python

Right now my flashcard game is using a `prepvocab()` method where I

- define the terms and translations for a week's worth of terms as a dictionary
- add a description of that week's terms
- lump them into a list of dictionaries, where a user selects their "weeks" to study

Every time I add a new week's worth of terms and translations, I'm stuck adding another element to the list of available dictionaries. I can definitely see this as not being a Good Thing.

```
class Vocab(object):

def __init__(self):
    vocab = {}
    self.new_vocab = vocab
    self.prepvocab()

def prepvocab(self):
    week01 = {"term":"translation"} #and many more...
    week01d = "Simple Latvian words"

    week02 = {"term":"translation"}
    week02d = "Simple Latvian colors"

    week03 = {"I need to add this":"to self.selvocab below"}
    week03d = "Body parts"

    self.selvocab = [week01, week02] #, week03, weekn]
    self.descs = [week01d, week02d] #, week03, weekn]
    Vocab.selvocab(self)

def selvocab(self):
    """I like this because as long as I maintain self.selvocab,
    the for loop cycles through the options just fine"""
    for x in range(self.selvocab):
        YN = input("Would you like to add week " \
                   + repr(x + 1) + " vocab? (y or n) \n" \
                   "Description: " + self.descs[x] + " ").lower()
        if YN in "yes":
            self.new_vocab.update(self.selvocab[x])
    self.makevocab()
```

I can definitely see that this is going to be a pain with 20+ yes no questions. I'm reading up on curses at the moment, and was thinking of printing all the descriptions at once, and letting the user pick all that they'd like to study for the round.

How do I keep this part of my code better maintained? Anybody got a radical overhaul that isn't so....procedural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pickling objects into a database](http://blog.cameronleger.com/2011/05/31/python-example-pickling-things-into-mysql-databases/) means it'll take some effort to create an interface to modify the weekly lessons from the front end, but is well worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your term:translation pairs and descriptions in a text file in some manner. Your program should then parse the text file and discover all available lessons. This will allow you to extend the set of lessons available without having to edit any code.

As for your selection of lessons, write a `print_lesson_choices` function that displays the available lessons and descriptions to the user, and then ask for their input in selecting them. Instead of asking a question of them for every lesson, why not make your prompt something like:

```
self.selected_weeks = []

def selvocab(self):
    self.print_lesson_choices()
    selection = input("Select a lesson number or leave blank if done selecting: ")
    if selection == "": #Done selecting
        self.makevocab()
    elif selection in self.available_lessons:
        if selection not in self.selected_weeks:
            self.selected_weeks.append(selection)
            print "Added lesson %s"%selection
        self.selvocab() #Display the list of options so the user can select again
    else:
        print "Bad selection, try again."
        self.selvocab()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have looked into this and, though I don't like the idea of leaving the python world for such a simple study aid, I did find [this](http://www.python.org/workshops/1997-10/proceedings/shprentz.html), which is what I was looking for (granted it is overkill).